Ruby version issue in osx 14.4
Okay, so... I have an M1 chip machine, with OSX 14.4 running on it. I wanted to install Ruby 3 with some gems and strange things happened... I used RVM for installing 3.4 onto my machine which was without any issues. But after it, I wanted to check the ruby version just to be sure and I saw 2.6.10 which makes no sense :/
Okay, it is possible that some years ago I installed it somehow with something I do not remember, but then I was not able to remove or update it, or to make the system to use the RVM version instead. I tried a lot of things but to no avail... Does anyone have any idea, how I could fix this issue once and for all, please?


Did you try rvm use ruby-3.4.0-preview1?
